# Executing .bat file remotely from Linux box

Tags: user-interface, batch-file

I'm trying to execute a .bat file on a windows box remotely from a Linux box by connecting via ssh, obtaining windows command prompt and then executing the batch file.

When I connect to the windows machine I can see that the process is running but the graphical interface is not being invoked.

Regards
Rahul

Comment: If you connect to a linux box you won't see a GUI (on the box) why should you see a GUI on windows?

Comment: The application that is executed on the windows box should open up a graphical UI, so when I login to the windows box I should be able to view it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you need to install x server on windows? Consider for xming as one option. I am assuming that you have installed ssh-server on windows system.

NOTE: You need to login on the windows box (once, after windows login), start the x server on windows & then onwards you should be able to ssh to the system & start the GUI application.

Another possible issue:

The ssh-server binary should be executed by the user, after logging in once after the windows system boot. Then ssh to that windows box, export DISPLAY=:0 & run GUI app.

**NOTE:** I have not tested any of the above 2 solution, but these are what I think as possible solutions.

One more solution:
Create a dedicated TCP based server (on windows) client (on linux) model & send commands over that channel. A dirty way & would be able to give limited functionality, but it is tested to be working.

Comment: The batch file when executed on the windows box directly runs everything normally, but when the same batch file is executed from the Linux box the UI does not appear, what could be the reason.

Comment: when you run directly, you already have GUI running - windows. When you connect from other system, it's actually the ssh-server which will spawn the shell, which would run the batch file. Please try the method # 2 mentioned above.